# The definition of the Sobolev spaces on $n$-dimensional torus

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

In Evans' book, the definition of the Sobolev space is

> $W^{k,p}(U)$ consists of all locally summable functions $u : U \to \mathbb{R}$ such that for each multiindex $\vert \alpha\vert \le k$, $D^{\alpha}u$ exists in the weak sense and belongs to $L^{p}(U)$.

Here, we suppose that the domain $U$ is open regardless of its boundedness. Then, what about **the Sobolev space on $n$-dimentional torus $\mathbb{T}^n$**? The domain is $\mathbb{R}^n/ \mathbb{Z}^n \equiv [0,1]^n$, which is sort of a closed set.

Then, on the domain of a closet set, can we define the Sobolev space in the sense of Evans', in other words, to define a weak derivative, we need a test function, which is a compact supported smooth function and so on. Then, what is the compact supported function on a torus? Or, should I go for the definition with respect to Fourier Analysis I'd appreciate it if you'd give me any help with understanding this or any reference to this!

Comment: The quotient $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ is $\mathbb{S}^1$, not $[0,1]$. Thus, the torus $\mathbb{T}^n$ is $(\mathbb{S}^1)^n$. It's a closed manifold (i.e., compact, without boundary), so every function is automatically compactly supported. I suggest first checking what the torus is, then checking "Sobolev spaces on manifolds" and also the definition using Fourier transform (which is special to $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{T}^n$).

Comment: @MichałMiśkiewicz Thank you! I concluded on my own that the test function, which is smooth and compactly supported in the domain, should just be any smooth periodic function, though I don't have any reference to compare this with...

Answer (score 2):

The usual definition is in terms of Fourier series.

For $k\in\mathbb{Z}^n$, let $\langle k\rangle = \sqrt{1+|k|^2}$, where $|k|^2=k_1^2+\dots+k_n^2$.

For a function $u$ on $\mathbb{T}^n$, consider the Fourier coefficient $\hat{u}_k = \int_{\mathbb{T}^n} e^{-2\pi i k\cdot x}u(x)dx$, so that $u = \sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}^n} \hat{u}_k e_k$ for $e_k(x)= e^{2\pi ik\cdot x}$.

Then for $s>0$, the Sobolev space is defined by
$$ H^s(\mathbb{T}^n) = \{u\in L^2(\mathbb{T}^n): \|u\|_{H^s(\mathbb{T}^n)}<\infty\},$$
where
$$ \|u\|_{H^s(\mathbb{T}^n)}^2 = \sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}^n}|\hat{u}_k|^2\langle k\rangle^{2s}$$